# Create an array by appending data from multiple tabs

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have a tab of data for each date within a range. I would like to combine the data from each tab into one big sheet.

The name of each tab is like this:

```
Jul - 06 - 2015, Jul - 07 - 2015, Jul - 08 - 2015, etc
```

I have two months of data, so ~60 tabs, one for each day.

For each tab I would like to create an array. If I was doing it manually I would go like this:

```
={'Jul - 06 - 2015'!A16:D;'Jul - 07 - 2015'!A16:D}
```

This appends two days of data, one underneath the other just as I'd like. I'd prefer not to type in 60 references.

In each case, the data I want are in A16:D for each tab. The length of data varies from day to day.

Is there something clever I can do here to create a new array with all my data combined into one big table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula using native functionality (ie with 60 range references) will always be more efficient in my opinion. You could use a script to create and populate the formula:

```
function populateFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var ranges = [];
  sheets.forEach(function(e) {
    var sheetName = e.getName();
    if (sheetName != activeSheetName)
      ranges.push("'" + sheetName + "'!A16:D");
  });
  if (ranges.length)
    ss.getActiveRange().setFormula("={" + ranges.join(";") + "}");
}
```

This will populate the formula in the active cell, referencing all sheets in the spreadsheet, except for the sheet in which the formula resides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam. I was holding out for a formula solution, e.g. could there be a way using indirect() and referencing a group of cells. For example, I have all the cell names written down in a long row of columns. If I could somehow give the range a name and then say "for each in range, get A16:D

Comment: Yes, I understand how that would be useful. As it stands, iteration over a range of cells is not possible with INDIRECT (in Sheets).